# How does Ollivander know which wand fits other wizards?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

When selecting wands, Ollivander does not seem to randomly pick boxes from his collection. How does he know which wand might be the right one?

Comment: Experience makes him pick a wand which might choose the wizard. If it doesn't, then he will change it. Remember the amount of time it took for Harry to get hands on his Phoenix feathered wand.

Comment: He has them fill out the Pottermore quiz.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the wand chooses the wizard, a knowledge of wandlore can help predict which wand would pick which wizard.

Taking from Olivander's notes on the subject:

> In  my  experience,  longer  wands  might  suit  taller  wizards,  but they  tend  to be  drawn  to  bigger  personalities,  and  those  of  a  more spacious  and dramatic  style of  magic.  Neater  wands  favour  more elegant  and  refined  spell-casting. However,  no  single aspect  of  wand  composition  should be  considered  in isolation of  all the  others,  and  the  type  of  wood,  the  core and  the flexibility  may  either  counterbalance or  enhance  the  attributes  of  the  wand’s  length.
>   <sub>(*[Pottermore - Wand Lengths and Flexibility](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-lengths-and-flexibilit)*)</sub>

Comment: It would therefore stand to reason that Ollivander should interview his customers prior to recommending wands for them, would it not?

Comment: @Yehuda - Perhaps he just asks them the seven questions on the Pottermore quiz.

Answer (score 1):

> Wands choose the wizard or witch in a way that is neither random, nor serendipitous. There is much ancient mythology and botanical knowledge regarding the powers and natures of wood and other natural elements. [Wandlore, Harry Potter Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wandlore)

This would be one of the insights an experienced wandmaker would use to know which wand could be a better fit for the wizard. But most of the time, it would be a trial and error. Also, most of the wands corresponds to the birth month's wood in the Celtic calendar, so that should really eliminate most of the extraneous candidates.

Comment: HP wiki isn't a reliable source.